# how to format writeLines as write.table? r

Tags: r, format

I'm running a loop and append data to an external file using write.table (see below). The issue is that the performance is not great because write.table needs to open and close the file after each write. 
 Question: How to achieve the same result using the file api?
e.g.

```
fl <-file("out.txt")
writeLines(as.character(result), fl)
close(fl)
```

Current formatting

```
write.table(result,  "out.csv", sep = ' ', col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T)
```

Comment: look for `paste` function.

Comment: You can pass `append = TRUE` to `write.csv()` or `write.table()`... Does that help? Why not just append directly from your loop?

Comment: @Mako212 The issue is that on each write.table or write.csv it needs to write and close the file so it's obviously an additional cost rather than to open the file just once append it millions of times and close it once after it's done.

Comment: @MKR paste seems to inline everything ..eg.  I get a single line instead of rows/columns that i get with `write.table`

Comment: Can you just append a `data.frame` from the loop and then write the `data.frame` out at the end?